# Route [pelicula.detalle] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

estoy teniendo el siguiente error 'Route [pelicula.detalle] not defined', y nose que puede llegar a ser.

Les muestro mi web.php:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PeliculaController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
    echo "Welcome";
});


Route::get('/peliculas/{pagina?}', [PeliculaController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/detalle', [PeliculaController::class, 'detalle']);

Route::resource('/usuario', UsuarioController::class);
```

detalle.blade.php:

```
<h1>Detalle Pelicula</h1>
<a href="{{ route('pelicula.detalle') }}">Ir al Listado</a>
```

PeliculaController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PeliculaController extends Controller
{
    public function index($pagina){

        $titulo = 'Listado de mis peliculas';

        return view('pelicula.index', [
            
            'titulo' => $titulo,
            'pagina' => $pagina
            
            ]);
    }


    public function detalle(){
        
        return view('pelicula.detalle');
        die();
    }
}
```

Estoy usando laravel 8 con php 7.4.9 y ya que me había quedado en versiones anteriores, estoy aprendiendo nuevamente a pasar rutas por links de blade. Leí la documentación de Laravel de esta versión pero no logre captar algo que me solucione el error. Si alguno puede ayudarme se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Pero efectivamente esa ruta no se ve declarada en algún lado, ¿a qué ruta de las que pusiste en tu pregunta es la que tratas de llamar?

Comment: @BetaM como que no esta definida? Route::get('/detalle', [PeliculaController::class, 'detalle']);

Comment: Pues ahi dice bien clarito **/detalle** no **pelicula.detalle**, son cosas distintas y por eso te falla, si quieres que ande entonces debes darle ese name a la ruta así: **`->name('pelicula.detalle');`**

Comment: @BetaM lo se pero tengo entendido que pelicula.detalle hace referencia al controller llamado PeliculaController y su metodo detalle. O no es asi?

Comment: No (**necesariamente**), en realidad hace referencia al name que pasas como te indiqué en mi comentario anterior, el error es claro tu helper **route** quiere encontrar una ruta que esté nombrada como **`pelicula.detalle`** la cual por supuesto no existe y el name **aunque debe llevar coherencia con el recurso solicitado** puede tener el name que **tu** desees

Answer (score 1):

Te comento:

- El método `route` (*helper ubicado en: `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`*) indica que y cito:

> Generate the URL to a named route

Entonces se valdrá del *string* que pases como argumento al método `name()` de la clase `Route` ubicada en: *`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php`*

Una vez expuesto lo anterior, entonces esta ruta:

```
Route::get('/detalle', [PeliculaController::class, 'detalle']);
```

Debe recibir el *name* de esta manera:

```
Route::get('/detalle', [PeliculaController::class, 'detalle'])->name('pelicula.detalle');
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior, el string que espera el método route para generar la URL será encontrado.

Por otro lado tal vez puedas considerar usar el string de la *uri* por medio del *helper `url`* de esta forma:

```
<a href="{{ url('detalle') }}">Ir al Listado</a>
```

Y en ambos casos deberías poder acceder al recurso solicitado

Te recomiendo los siguientes enlaces:

- [*Rutas nombradas*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes)
- [*Helper `route`*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route)
- [*Helper `url`*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url)